# r data.table - use string to create a summarized column from n columns

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I have som data in a data.table that I want to to sum. Trivial example supplied below. I start with (variable) n-columns (char) and some group variables.

I can convert them (nsk-vars in my example) to numeric/integer beforehand, if that's the way to go. I would like to be able to use a string of columnames to create a new column which is the sum of these(nsk1-nsk3) and handle NA:s. How do I do this in a resonable way?

```
library(data.table)

x <- data.table(a    = c("GrpA", "GrpB"),
                nsk1 = c("1","3"),
                nsk2 = c(NA,"1"),
                nsk3 = c("3", "4"))

ClNamesStr <- colnames(x)
ClNamesStr <- ClNamesStr[grepl("^nsk", ClNamesStr)]

nskStrSum <- paste(ClNamesStr, collapse = "),as.numeric(")
nskStrSum <- paste("as.numeric(", nskStrSum, "), na.rm = TRUE")
```

This is the part that I would like to get working.

```
x[, nsk0 := sum(eval(nskStrSum)), by = a]
```

The desired output would be this:

```
a    nsk1 nsk2 nsk3 nsk0
GrpA    1   NA    3    4
GrpB    3    1    4    8
```

Comment: thx @lmo - realised I might have made my example to simple. I have other columns that aren't group vars but shouldn't be summarized. ofc, I could just group by them aswell I guess?

Comment: Are you trying to sum a set of variables that are character by row? Please include your desired output in the question.

Comment: Absolutely - if  I write it in plain text it works, but I would need to generate the sum-expression string from the extracted colnames, and that's the part that isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to go.

```
x[, nsk0 := rowSums(sapply(.SD, function(i) as.numeric(i)), na.rm=TRUE),
  .SDcols=grep("^nsk", names(x)), by = a]
```

which returns

```
x
      a nsk1 nsk2 nsk3 othr nsk0
1: GrpA    1   NA    3    a    4
2: GrpA    3    1    4    b    8
```

`sapply` runs through the selected variables, converts each to a numeric and returns a matrix. This matrix is passed to `rowSums` which sums up the values in each row and ignores the `NA`s. `.SD` is a shorthand to select of the data.table, (except variables contained in "by"). However, the variables are selected among them using `.SDcols` along with `grep`.

Some data.tablers might not be happy with this solution as it converts some of the data into a matrix. However, this conversion may be necessary in your case.

I added an additional "nuisance" variable to show that it will work.

**data**

```
x <- data.table(a    = c("GrpA", "GrpA"),
                nsk1 = c("1","3"),
                nsk2 = c(NA,"1"),
                nsk3 = c("3", "4"), 
                othr = letters[1:2])
```

Comment: Thx for the edit as well. I surmised what you did there, but hadn't thought about using .SDcols with grep before this, that  was a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `Reduce` after replacing the 'NA' with 0.

```
i1 <- grep("nsk", names(x))
x[, nsk0 := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
       as.numeric(replace(x, is.na(x), 0)))), .SDcols = i1]
x
#      a nsk1 nsk2 nsk3 othr nsk0
#1: GrpA    1   NA    3    a    4
#2: GrpA    3    1    4    b    8
```